# How to add new ip phone cisco and new line with Java using AXL API CUCM 6?

Tags: java, cisco-axl, cucm

I want to add a new ip phone and new line with Java using AXL API of Cisco Call Manager 6.
Here is my code:

```
        XRoutePartition partition = new XRoutePartition();
        partition.setName("PT_INTERNAL");

        XNPDirectoryNumber dirn = new XNPDirectoryNumber();
        dirn.setPattern("1006");
        dirn.setRoutePartition(partition);
        XLine phoneLine = new XLine();
        phoneLine.setDirn(dirn);

        XLine[] phoneLineArray = new XLine[1];
        phoneLineArray[0] = phoneLine;

        AddLineReq addLine = new AddLineReq();
        addLine.setNewLine(dirn);
        XIPPhone.Lines lines = new XIPPhone.Lines();
        lines.getLine().add(0, phoneLine);
        XIPPhone xp = new XIPPhone();

        xp.setName("SEP64168D50552C");
        xp.setDescription("Laroussi Nader Test");
        xp.setProduct("Cisco 7911");
        xp.setClazz("Phone");
        xp.setModel("Cisco 7911");
        xp.setProtocol("SCCP");

        xp.setProtocolSide("User");
        xp.setDefaultProfileName("Standard Common Phone Profile");
        //XDevicePool devicePool = new XDevicePool();
        //devicePool.setName("Default");
        xp.setDevicePoolName("Default");
        //XLocation location = new XLocation();
        //location.setName("Hub_None");
        xp.setLocationName("Hub_None");
        xp.setLines(lines);

        AddPhoneReq addPhoneReq = new AddPhoneReq(); 
        addPhoneReq.setNewPhone(xp);
        StandardResponse response = axlPort.addPhone(addPhoneReq);
```

the SOAP response is: **The specified name has invalid characters or is not formatted correctly for this device type.**

What can I do to resolve this problem? Thank you